# Multiple devices on I2C bus

Tags: i2c, routing

I design a board and I need around 5-8 chips connected on I2C bus. What's the main routing considerations on routing topology for multiple devices?
I was thinking that daisy chain topology would be better instead of star routing or any other topology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I2C is so slow that you don't really worry about propagation delays along the bus or routing topology. Your main goal should be to minimize the capacitance of the bus wiring, which means minimizing the total track length. But you don't need to optimize every detail. If your track lengths are under 30 cm or so your devices will likely dominate the capacitance anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I2C is so slow that we need not worry about transmission line effects.

That means, use daisy chain, star, or a mix of both whatever is most convenient locally, and it will still work.